# How can I add iAds from a specific category in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I want to integrate ads (banner) in a particular category to my iPad Application (Category like ads from financial sectors, IT Sector etc). Is there any ad service that support this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing a bit of research, and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to filter ads by category on either iAd or Adsense, instead relying on "algorithms" to choose ads. That said, Adsense offers the ability to *block* by category, so in theory you could block less relevant categories. Directions can be found at [this page](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/186376?hl=en). Though this is a convoluted way, it appears to be the only, short of just trusting the terrible in my experience algorithms.

On another note, buysellads works by having you approve ads before they show, sy you could accept only some ads that way. Info about the iOS SDK is [here.](http://blog.buysellads.com/2010/buysellads-com-ios-developer-framework/)

Hope this helps!